# Keeping Open Sidemenu

Tags: javascript, reactjs, submenu, side-menu

I want to keep open my sidemenu but i don't know how to do.

```
    const Dep2Handler = (e) => {
      const classOnTarget = e.target.parentElement;
      const onRemoveTarget = classOnTarget.parentElement.children;

      if (classOnTarget.classList.contains("on")) {
          classOnTarget.classList.remove("on");
      }
      else {
        for (let i = 0; i < onRemoveTarget.length; i++) {
          onRemoveTarget[i].classList.remove("on");
        }
        classOnTarget.classList.add("on");
      }      
     
    };
/*     useLayoutEffect(()=>{
      
    },[sideNaviPos]) */

    const Dep3Handler = (e,props) => {   
      const classOnTarget = e.target;
      const onRemoveTarget = classOnTarget.parentElement.children;

      classOnTarget.classList.add("on");
    };


--------------------------------------------------------------------
 <ol>
          <li>
            <p onClick={Dep2Handler} sidebar={sidebar}></p>
            <ol className="has_dep3">
              <li onClick={Dep3Handler} value="space"><button className="btn" onClick={(e)=>history("/info")}></button></li>
              <li onClick={Dep3Handler} value="equip"><button className="btn" onClick={(e)=>history("/info/info/equipinfo")}></button></li>
              <li onClick={Dep3Handler} value="work"><button className="btn" onClick={(e)=>history("/info/info/workerinfo")}></button></li>
            </ol>
          </li>
          <li>
            <p onClick={Dep2Handler}></p>
            <ol className="has_dep3">
              <li onClick={Dep3Handler}><button onClick={(e)=>history("/admin/info/greetings")}></button></li>
              <li onClick={Dep3Handler}><button onClick={(e)=>history("/admin/info/vision")}></button></li>
              <li onClick={Dep3Handler}><button onClick={(e)=>history("/admin/info/organization")}></button></li>
              <li onClick={Dep3Handler}><button onClick={(e)=>history("/admin/info/partner")}></button></li>
            </ol>
          </li>
          <li>
         <p onClick={(e)=>{Dep2Handler(e);history("/info/way")}}></p>
          </li>
          <li>
          <p onClick={(e)=>{Dep2Handler(e);history("/info/faq")}}></p>
          </li>
        </ol>
```

if i click children of first li menu, keeping open then click another one the previous will be close and clicked menu open. Is it possible without use redux?

Answer (score 1):

There is quite a bit to unpack here so I apologize in advance if this post ends up longer than you desired.

First off, and to address your question about Redux

> Is it possible without use redux?

Most definitely. Lots of people used React before redux was a thing and for some apps even today can get away without redux (using [the Context API](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context) is an option).

Before just showing you to code let me comment on some of your existing code

> `classOnTarget.classList.add("on");`

by doing this you are effectively using the [DOM's classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to hold your state rather than React. While there are cases that something like that might be needed (e.g. you are introducing some react components into an existing codebase) I don't think that's the case here and we should change that.

Let's start small, what if you want to have a single menu open or close. One approach could be to have something like

```
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
...
return <div className={isOpen ? 'on' : ''}>...</div>
```

The, maybe obvious, next step is *what if I have two menus*?

```
const [isFirstOpen, setIsFirstOpen] = useState(false);
const [isSecondOpen, setIsSecondOpen] = useState(false);
...
return (
  <div className={isFirstOpen || isSecondOpen ? 'on' : ''}>
    <div className={isFirstOpen ? 'active' : ''}>First</div>
    <div className={isSecondOpen ? 'active' : ''}>Second</div>
  </div>
);
```

but the above code is neither pretty nor scalable (what if I have 10 items in the menu?). So instead of representing the state of each possible menu you might want to keep track of *which one* is open/active

```
const [activeRoute, setActiveRoute] = useState();
...
return (
  <div className={activeRoute ? 'on' : ''}>
    <div className={activeRoute === 'first' ? 'active' : ''}>First</div>
    <div className={activeRoute === 'second' ? 'active' : ''}>Second</div>
  </div>
);
```

Now, we want the active route to change based on what is being clicked

```
const [activeRoute, setActiveRoute] = useState();
const navigateTo = (newRoute) => {
  history(newRoute);
  setActiveRoute(newRoute);
};
...
return (
  <div className={activeRoute ? 'on' : ''}>
    <div className={activeRoute === '/first' ? 'active' : ''}
      onClick={() => navigateTo('/first')}>First</div>
    <div className={activeRoute === '/second' ? 'active' : ''}
      onClick={() => navigateTo('/second')}>Second</div>
  </div>
);
```

Now you might ask, well that's all nice and dandy but how do I deal with a nested menu? like in your case.

You might notice in your existing code that all the `onClick` handlers happen in the deepest (the most nested) `li` / `button`, not on the first level of the menu.

So lets say that on your first level you just want to add a class so it looks like that's the active menu.

```
const MENU_MAP = {
  '/first': 'menuA',
  '/second': 'menuA',
  '/third': 'menuB',
  '/fourth': 'menuB',
};

const [activeRoute, setActiveRoute] = useState();
const navigateTo = (newRoute) => {
  history(newRoute);
  setActiveRoute(newRoute);
};
const activeMenu = activeRoute ? MENU_MAP[activeRoute] : null;
...
return (
  <div>
    <div className={activeMenu === 'menuA' ? 'open' : ''}>
      <div className={activeRoute ? 'on' : ''}>
        <div className={activeRoute === '/first' ? 'active' : ''}
          onClick={() => navigateTo('/first')}>First</div>
        <div className={activeRoute === '/second' ? 'active' : ''}
          onClick={() => navigateTo('/second')}>Second</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div className={activeMenu === 'menuB' ? 'open' : ''}>
      <div className={activeRoute ? 'on' : ''}>
        <div className={activeRoute === '/third' ? 'active' : ''}
          onClick={() => navigateTo('/third')}>Third</div>
        <div className={activeRoute === '/fourth' ? 'active' : ''}
          onClick={() => navigateTo('/fourth')}>Fourth</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

I hope you can see a pattern in the above and apply that to your specific HTML requirements of using `ol`, `li`, `button`. Hope this helps

--

For anyone other than the OP reading this and thinking "this could be cleaner" or "we could use `useContext`" or "we could add an abstraction here and here", save it. The verbosity on my answer to hopefully help the OP see the pattern so they can figure out a solution; this is not about showing off you know redux or mobX or how to use hooks.